# Regular expression for matching criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I want a RegX for

input must have 
-1 Uppercase letters 
-1 Lowercase letters 
-1 Punctuation 
-1 Numbers

At lease 3 criteria matched from above.

Comment: exactly what you are looking for? can you tell us in brief?

Answer (score 0):

Make it work with if expression.

What you can do is to check string in groups like this :

```
string pass = Password.Text;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(pass, @"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*") || Regex.IsMatch(pass, @"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).*") || Regex.IsMatch(pass, @"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*(?=.*\W).*") || Regex.IsMatch(pass, @"(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*(?=.*\W).*"))
            {
                lbl.Text = "ahah..!!";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl.Text = "Oooops";
            }
```

Hope this will help you..!!